# Why mobile browser not saving session vairalble?

Tags: laravel

As soon as the system ask for location and receives latitude and longitude. These values should be stored in a session. I have stored session in backend. Everything works fine in mobile browser it ask for location but doesn't store session.
I have tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "{{route('storesession')}}",
                data: {
                    latitude: latitude,
                    longitude: longitude
                },
                success: function (res) {
                    $('#futsallist').html(res)
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: So where do you store session? In server side? In that case, you have to share server side code. And you cannot access directly in javascript.

Comment: @bravemaster Yes i have stored session in serverside. i want to get session value in controller. It works in desktop but doesn't work in mobiles

Comment: What did you do in `storesession` route? Can you add server side code?